# Saving the state of the LED on illuminated momentary button

Tags: switches, flipflop, logic-gates, latch

I have three illuminated momentary buttons with a separate anode and cathode for the led.

[image] ([source](https://www.creatroninc.com/1275-large_default/led-tactile-switch-orange.jpg) of image)

I want a circuit that illuminates the LED of the button that was most recently pushed.

My initial idea has been to use three SR Latches created using NOR gates. Connect the S or Q of each latch to the reset of the two other latches. But then this creates the opportunity for HIGH on both S and R which is disallowed. Right?

I imagine there are other ways to accomplish this without latches too. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: single chip solution - small micro controller.

Comment: If you disallow the possibility of multiple switches being pressed simultaneously you can use Ignacio's circuit. Otherwise a micro would be simple, or you could capacitively couple to the inputs of Ignacio's circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circuit you're looking for is called a ["flip-flap-flop"](http://www.goldenmuseum.com/1411FlipFlap_engl.html). It is essentially a 3-state (rather than 2-state) flip-flop. It can be implemented using a single 74xx27. It is the circuit on the right below:

[image: flip-flop and flip-flap-flop]

Comment: Thank you that seems exactly the type of solution I was going for.